# Faster alternative to split-apply-combine

Tags: r, performance, data-structures, plyr

#### the short version

Split-apply-combine with `plyr::dlply` seems to be inefficient because of the  overhead required to split and combine. Am I mistaken, or is there a better/faster way?

---

#### the long version

I am fitting several thousand vector autoregressions in R with a function that is something like a glorified wrapper/extractor for `vars::VAR`. I'll just call it `estim`.

Right now, my data is in "long" format, e.g.

```
dd <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), time = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L), x = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), y = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L)), .Names = c("id", 
"time", "x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

that I am processing with `output <- plyr::dlply(dd, .(id), myFun)`.

With ~4,800 unique ID's and 182 time points for each, I get

```
system.time(output <- plyr::dlply(dd, .(id), estimate, .parallel = FALSE))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 37.357   0.730  38.048
```

and

```
registerDoMC(detectCores() - 1) # I have 4 cores
system.time(output <- plyr::dlply(dd, .(id), estimate, .parallel = TRUE))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 57.234   6.710  23.593
```

on my MacBook (2.8 GHz i7 with 16 GB RAM).

Doing it in parallel doesn't save as much time as I'd hoped. This suggests to me that the "slow" part of this operation is not in computing `estimate` but somewhere in the splitting and combining steps employed by `dplyr`.

The split-apply-combine paradigm is nice for interactive and medium-scale use (and at least in this case is much faster than looping), but I suspect that better approaches are out there. Should I reshape the data to "wide" format, e.g.

```
dd.wide <- structure(list(time = 1:4, `1_x` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), `1_y` = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L), `2_x` = c(6L, 2L, 3L, 2L), `2_y` = c(2L, 0L, 2L, 
0L), `3_x` = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), `3_y` = c(0L, 3L, 3L, 0L)), .Names = c("time", 
"1_x", "1_y", "2_x", "2_y", "3_x", "3_y"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

and then apply `myFun` to pairs of columns?

**Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?** Alternatively, can I make better use of parallelization here? Or is this as fast as it's going to get?

And finally, let's say now I want to do

```
estim2 <- function(param) ddply(dd, .(id), estim, foo = param)
output.list <- lapply(1:10, estim2)
```

Does the answer change at all? I'm particularly interested in the "right" way to parallelize this nested looping, although I'm sure that's been covered on this site before.

Comment: "splitting and combining steps employed by dplyr" How about trying this with dplyr instead of plyr (which is the package you are using right now)? I prefer data.table, but dplyr *is* much faster than plyr. If you ask for performance recommendations you should provide code that is reproducible and creates data of the scale you are dealing with.

Comment: @Roland: + 1 for data.table

Comment: I like data.table (and dplyr) as well, but can I get it to return an arbitrary list as I have here? I'm pretty new to both.

Comment: Make your question a reproducible example and my estimate is that you'll know within 15 minutes if it is possible for what you want to do or not (and potentially how it might be done in a different way).

Comment: As @Roland and others pointed out, your answer is completely dependent on the function you are using.  Getting a 2x speedup on 4 cores sounds reasonable, since at least part of the time is spent on the overhead of communicating between cores and collating results.  Your solution at the moment takes about 5 microseconds per id.  How much faster do you want it to be?  Anyway, fine-tuning at this level  depends on reducing inefficiencies at each step of the process.  Post a completely reproducible example.

Comment: I just realized that 5 microseconds times 4800 id's = 24 seconds. And running the real function takes about 7 microseconds. So the answer is "dlply is plenty fast, but the inner function is slow." I also get a ~5 second speedup with data.table on the MWE I was about to post, using `dd <- data.table(dd, key = "id"); out <- data.table[, estim(.SD$x, .SD$y), by = id]` Thanks for the comments anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the comments, my suspicion about overhead is wrong. The inner function takes ~7 microseconds to execute, and .007 * 4800 = 33.6 seconds.

So with regard to:

> Split-apply-combine with plyr::dlply seems to be inefficient because of the overhead required to split and combine. Am I mistaken, or is there a better/faster way?

The answer is that

> It would probably be unreasonable to expect serious speedups without making the inner function faster.

I am, in fact, mistaken.